# htaccess Rewrite Rules for Magento Multisite with WordPress blog

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I have a Magento installation running 2 websites:

www.mywebsite1.co.uk
www.mywebsite2.co.uk

We had a blog extension that was used, however now we've switch the blog on mywebsite1.co.uk to WordPress.

This is stored in www.mywebsite1.co.uk/blog directory

However, now when you go to mywebsite2.co.uk/blog, you are taken to www.mywebsite1.co.uk/blog because the /blog directory exists for mywebsite2.co.uk.

Is there a way I can either:

1. Tell requests to mywebsite2.co.uk/blog to ignore the /blog directory
2. Move the WordPress installation to a new directory but keep the url as mywebsite1.co.uk/blog

EDIT:

Magento has the following Rewrite condition in it's htaccess file that tells it not to apply the default Magento rewrites to directories.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I need to somehow overwrite this, or work around in why people visit from HTTP_HOST mywebsite2.co.uk and REQUEST_URI ^/blog/

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite2\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell me which blog extesion you install in magento2?

Comment: It'c called BlogMate by Magik. I think it came with a theme